# How to enable auto nontype template parameter pack for same type of parameters

Tags: c++, c++17, non-type, non-type-template-parameter

I have the following code:

```
template<auto... args> struct Custom
{
};
int main()
{
    Custom<1, nullptr> s; // i want this to succeed only when all the template arguments are of the same type    
}
```

As is evident from the above code, i can pass template arguments of different types. My question is that is there a way to only accept template arguments of the same type. This means, that the statement inside the `main` should fail and should only work when all the template arguments are of the same type. Essentially, there are 2 requirements:

1. The code should not work for less than 1 template argument. That is, at least one template argument must be present. If the user provides 0 template arguments then it should not work.
2. The code should not work for different type of template arguments.

I don't if this is even possible. I was thinking of maybe using `enable_if` or some other feature but i don't know what might help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `decltype` construct as shown below:

```
template<auto T1, decltype(T1)... Args> struct Custom
{
};
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/zjc-ORE2X)

Comment: This still allows multiple types of arguments, e.g., `Custom<0, 'a'>` (converting the `char` to an `int`). I can't say for sure whether the question was more precise there than intended.

Comment: `char` data type is an **integral type** meaning the underlying data is stored as an integer anyhow. It should not make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way in C++17 is to use `static_assert`

```
#include <type_traits>

template<auto first, auto... rest> 
struct Custom {
  static_assert(
    (std::is_same_v<decltype(first), decltype(rest)> && ...),
  "non-type template parameter pack must be the same type.");
};
```

In C++20, you can just use concepts:

```
#include <concepts>

template<auto first, auto... rest> 
  requires (std::same_as<decltype(first), decltype(rest)> && ...)
struct Custom {
  
};
```

Comment: Yes, it is C++17 fold expression, which we can use to expand the template pack as `(is_same_v<T1, T2> && is_same_v<T1, T3> && is_same_v<T1, T4> ...)`.